# can't unwrap optional in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, swift

I'm using Parse, and getting a PFUsers objectId like so:

```
let objectID = PFUser.currentUser().objectId;
```

but every time I run my app and the app gets to this line I get this:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

and if I try to change to this:

```
let objectID = PFUser.currentUser().objectId!;
```

I can't do this next line :`if (objectID != nil)` because NSString doesn't conforms to `NiLiteralConvertible`

Comment: drop the semi colons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optional here is the return value from `PFUser.currentUser()` not the `objectId`.

You need change this slightly as it may be possible that the current user doesn't exist.

Something like...

```
if let user = PFUser.currentUser()! {
    let objectID = user.objectId
}
```

or something. Not quite sure though as I haven't got into Swift properly yet.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
    let user: PFUser? = PFUser.currentUser()
    if user != nil
    {
        let objectID = user!.objectId
    }
```

or if objectId can be nil:

```
    let user: PFUser? = PFUser.currentUser()
    if user != nil
    {
        if let objectID = user!.objectId?
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was trying to think of.

Comment: Don't manually unwrap and check the optionals. Use if let for both user and objectID